# RenderPadding object was given an infinite size during layout

Tags: flutter, widget

I was trying to have another widget in my flutter page so instead of having a container I used (column /list view )

this is the code (main things have red line )
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZOTn.png)

now Im getting these errors
child: RenderPointerListener#c3ba4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
parentData: 
constraints: MISSING
size: MISSING
behavior: deferToChild
listeners: down
child: ChartContainerRenderObject#c7bf3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
parentData: 
constraints: MISSING
semantic boundary
size: MISSING
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderPadding object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was
SafeArea
lib\dept.dart:62
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
lib\dept.dart:60

Answer (score 0):

the issue was solved by adding height:value to the container
child: ListView(
shrinkWrap: true,
children: [
Container(
height: 400,
child: SafeArea(.......)),
Container(child:new Text("palestine");))

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by adding Flexible to your widget.